# I uninstalled this packages when Chromium was uninstalled

Tags: apt, package-management, chromium

today i downloaded chromium from the Ubuntu Software Center but it doesnt work, so i decided to uninstall it via Terminal using the --purge remove command.

When it was uninstalled, ubuntu told me about some packages that i could remove using the command sudo apt-get autoremove, it removed three packages, one of them related to Chromium but the other two where these:

1. linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic (4.4.0-21.37)
2. linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic (4.4.0-28.47)

i removed them.
Is there any security and/or stability risks?

Should i reinstall them?

Thanks!

Comment: Those are old (unused) kernel images. You should be fine.

Comment: thanks mate :), i was kinda scared when it told me that i may have broken the grub, fortunately it didn't happen